# Retrieving status code when using pipelines

Tags: scripts

I run the following command in a bash script:

```
cd SomeDir && (sh -c "$CMD_STR") 2>&1 | some_filtering | sed -u -e ....
```

I.e. I run CMD_STR in SomeDir (actually CMD_STR is 'make' or 'make target'), do some filtering on CMD_STR's output and then replace some symbols by 'sed'.

I need to retrieve CMD_STR's status code in case CMD_STR fails to return it from my script. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set 'pipefail' option before running the command.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

> If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of
>   the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero
>   if all commands exit successfully.

So now my script looks like the following:

```
set -o pipefail
cd SomeDir && (sh -c "$CMD_STR") 2>&1 | some_filtering | sed -u -e ....
exit $?
```

Answer (score 0):

To check last exit status code in bash shell, you can use:

```
echo $?
```

Also you said that you use that command in a script, so, to retrieve status code, you can run that script as follow:

```
sh -x /path/to/script
```

or

```
bash -x /path/to/script
```

Other options are to use `set -x` and `set +x` commands in the script to retrieve status code for parts of the script.

More about:

- [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html).

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. Because of "the exit status is the exit status of the last command specified in the pipeline". See 'man sh'. So it's sed's, not CMD's.

Comment: @Roman Please read all answer, not only the first line.